# How to write main function in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I got below code, but my main function doesn't work. Can anyone help? Thank you!

The quetion is: 
Given a string s, return the last substring of s in lexicographical order.

Example 1:

Input: "abab"
Output: "bab"
Explanation: The substrings are ["a", "ab", "aba", "abab", "b", "ba", "bab"]. The lexicographically maximum substring is "bab".

The IDE said;

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "F:/!!!PDF/!!!PyCharmWorkspace/LeetCode/AA1163LastSubstringInLexicographicalOrder3.py", line 
 1, in <module>
 class Solution:
 File "F:/!!!PDF/!!!PyCharmWorkspace/LeetCode/AA1163LastSubstringInLexicographicalOrder3.py", line 
 20, in Solution
 print(lastSubstring(s))
TypeError: lastSubstring() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

Below is my code.

```
class Solution:
def lastSubstring(self, s: str) -> str:
    i, indexes = 0, list(range(len(s)))
    while len(indexes) > 1:
        new = []
        mx = max([s[i + j] for j in indexes if i + j < len(s)])
        for k, j in enumerate(indexes):
            if k - 1 >= 0 and indexes[k - 1] + i == j:
                continue
            if i + j >= len(s):
                break
            if s[i + j] == mx:
                new.append(j)
        i += 1
        indexes = new
    return s[indexes[0]:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "leetcode"
    print(lastSubstring(s))
```

Comment: your code procuces an `IndentationError`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use class function while you didn't create an instance of this class.
There are two ways to solve this issue.

First - Declare the *lastSubstring* as [classmethod](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classmethod-in-python/):

> classmethod() methods are bound to class rather than an object. Class
>   methods can be called by both class and object. These methods can be
>   call with class or with object. Below examples illustrates above
>   clearly.

```
class Solution:
@classmethod
def lastSubstring(self, s: str) -> str:
    i, indexes = 0, list(range(len(s)))
    while len(indexes) > 1:
        new = []
        mx = max([s[i + j] for j in indexes if i + j < len(s)])
        for k, j in enumerate(indexes):
            if k - 1 >= 0 and indexes[k - 1] + i == j:
                continue
            if i + j >= len(s):
                break
            if s[i + j] == mx:
                new.append(j)
        i += 1
        indexes = new
    return s[indexes[0]:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "leetcode"
    print(Solution.lastSubstring(s))
```

Second - Create an instance from the *Solution* class first:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "leetcode"
    sol= Solution()
    print(sol.lastSubstring(s))
```